# Bounddeness in $L^p$ norm implies boundedness in infinity norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Assume $f\in L^p$ and $||f||_p\le C$ for every $1<p<\infty$. Prove that $f\in L^\infty$ and $||f||_\infty\le C$.

I know that from a problem in Folland (Problem 7 on Page 187), if $f\in L^\infty$, then the infinity norm is the limit of the p norm, but I don't know how to show $f\in L^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$fI_{\{x:|f(x)| \leq n\}}$ is an $L^{\infty}$ function so by the problem you have quoted we get $\|fI_{\{x:|f(x)| \leq n\}}\|_{\infty} \leq C$. If you let $n \to \infty$ you see that $f \in L^{\infty}$ and  $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq C$.

Comment: Actually the result of Problem 7 is valid even if $f \notin L^{\infty}$ (in which case $\|f\|_p \to \infty$ as $ p\to \infty)$.

Comment: Is the method above to reduce the condition $f\in L^\infty$ in problem 7?

Comment: Yes, this is the way you can avoid the assumption that $f \in L^{\infty}$.